# uiimagepicker differentiate where the call was made

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, grand-central-dispatch

I guess this is a two part question.  First part is: I have a view controller where there are two Image Views, both user inter-actable.  In both I call:

```
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary]) {
    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

And the delegate method handles the picked image form the photo library.  But right now I have to way of choosing which Image View gets that picture unless I make a custom UIView with two buttons where the user picks the Image View.  It's more clicks and not very practical.  I tried making another NSObject file but it can't use [self presentViewController...].  Calling the method in a new View Controller can't present UIImagePickerController because it's not in the window hierarchy.  Is there a way to differentiate inside didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo which Image View calls the picker?

And maybe this second part of the question doesn't really belong here but it still has to do with pictures.  If the user selects one picture and adds it to the gallery, goes and selects another and another...lets say 10 pictures...what's the best way of doing this, I mean GCD or NSOperationQueue?  Reason why I'm asking is what if the user is on a slow mobile internet connection and after loading them to either GCD or NSOpQueue they leave the view controller...will those images continue loading to the server?  I know you can make an order with NSOpQueue and I guess you can cancel the operation when the viewWillDisappear...Is that the way to do it?

I know it's a log of writing and not a lot of code but trying to learn the best way to go about all this.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my experience of what I've done in similar situations, I hope this helps.

First, regarding the initial part of your question, you have not way of reading the parameters of the method  didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo to determine what UIImageView was the one pressed. But you can easily keep a reference to the lastPressedImageView in you view controller and keep it as simply as reading this variable once you receive didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo.

Regarding the second part of your question I recommend you reading / researching about [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) which is a really powerful and easy to learn library for networking in iOS. You'd need to add your own logic to create the requests and send them, as well as for controlling possible errors, but this lib will help you to concentrate on logic instead of low-level networking concerns.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.  I haven't been learning for a long time so I haven't encountered lastPressedImageView.  Can you provide an example of how this would work with two ImageViews?

Comment: You would have the following property on your private viewController interface: @property(nonatomic,strong) UIImageView * lastPressedImageView;   … Later on the method where you present the view controller you need to assign this property to the view that was pressed and that triggered the method to presentViewController.

Comment: That actually sparked an idea about the first part...I could just have a string declare in the view controller, when one image is clicked, I could set the string as image 1.  When the delegate method is called, I could check which image was clicked and set it there.  Seems simple enough!

Comment: Sure, using an string is also a related simple idea. Good luck with the implementation!